# Energy Decomposition Analysis for SN2 involving ambident nucleophiles and an alkali metal counterion

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, physical-organic-chemistry

I am wanting to perform an EDA on transition state structure of the nucleophilic attack of an ambident nucleophile (2 atoms that could be used in nucleophilic attack on the same molecule) on a benzyl halide. I currently have access to Gaussian16 and ORCA, as well as any other open source software that is available. I am trying to understand what factors should be of greatest importance to these transition states, but I am unsure of what EDA to use to probe this question.
I am aware of SAPT, EDA-NOCV, and ALMO-COVP for energy decomposition analyses, but was hoping to hear of any more methods I could incorporate (that I can get access to) and/or thoughts on what dominating factors in this process (i.e., which EDA method is more applicable). I'd also like to fill any gaps in knowledge, if anyone has the time to lend me a hand.

Thanks, and all the best.